# Moving the window in the Form1.cs[DESIGN]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer, toolbox

The problem is when i open the toolbox it blocks some of the form.

[image]

Like in the picture.
So how do i move the form to the middle of the screen or somewhere else?

Off curse this is VS2013 Using c# Windows forms application.

Comment: Why do you need to? Click the `pin` icon to dock the Toolbox, or simply click the object in the Toolbox once, move away from it, and click-and-drag it into the form.

Comment: Thanks man. now just from curiosity, is that even possible to move it?

Comment: No. You can use WPF if you want to be able to do that, and I suggest you use WPF anyway. (It's MUCH more extensible.)

Comment: you can also dock the toolbar (and any of the other myriad windows that VS uses) anywhere you want by dragging them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as i thought you can't. 
you can click the pin icon to dock the Toolbox.